# Lockfiles in Bash: Text file busy when running two copies at once

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a Bash script that needs to lock a file for exclusive read/write while it runs.  During this time, any other copies of the same script running should hang until the lock is released (which should be pretty quickly).

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "rm -f /tmp/.lock; exit" 0 1 2 3 15

(
    flock -x 100 

    # Stuff happens here...

) 100>/tmp.lock
```

This works, somewhat.  But not in these conditions:

1. Start script copy #1
2. Start script copy #2
3. End script copy #1 before script copy #2 does

At this point, I get the error:

```
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/.lock': Text file busy
```

I assume I'm totally wrong on how I'm cleaning things up with the trap, so any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You lock files and not filenames, so I would question removing this file at all: you can run as many instances of `( flock -x 100; echo lock grabbed; rm /tmp/lol; sleep 60; ) 100> /tmp/lol` as you want, and they'll all successfully lock `/tmp/lol` at the same time because the same filename keeps referring to different files.

Comment: BTW, most systems will allow this `rm -f` to happen without any `text file busy` error, instead silently breaking your locking. Consider yourself lucky that your particular Linux distro provides security hardening that saved you from this bug.

Comment: (On a different point -- trapping `0` would be sufficient; an EXIT trap covers all cases of exiting due to trappable signals).

Answer (score 5):

**DO NOT EVER** try to "clean up" flock-style lockfiles whenever it is possible that any program holding that lock could be running or attempting to run.

Keep in mind that locks are held on *inodes*, not *filenames*. Deleting a directory entry decouples the inode previously at that location from its name, allowing that name to then refer to a different inode.

Consider the following scenario:

1. Program A holds a lock.
2. Program B opens the lockfile and tries to grab a lock on it, blocking until Program A is done with the lock.
3. Program A finishes; closes the lock; and deletes the lockfile.
4. Program B *still holds a handle on the deleted lockfile*. As Program A closed the lock (or exited, releasing its file handle and thus its lock), Program B is able to continue running, holding that handle as its lock.
5. Program C tries to grab the lock. **Even though Program B is still running, because the lockfile Program B holds a handle on was deleted by Program A, Program C is allowed to run concurrently.**
6. Program B exits, deleting the lockfile that Program C created, while Program C is still running.

---

Flock-file lockfiles should be considered mappings from filesystem namespace into file-locking namespace. These mappings do not need to be, and should not be, "cleaned up". You may wish to consider whether your operating system's filesystem hierarchy standard provides a places for such files to live, such as `/var/lock`, or somewhere on `tmpfs` (where "cleanup" will happen implicitly -- and safely -- on reboot).